# Diagnostic, diy repair guides, technical manuals

Tags: engine, maintenance

So I was wondering for a list of good diy diagnostic, repair softwares (not obd).

I am aware of Autodata, Vivid and Mitchell on Demand.

What else do you know? I am also looking for a software that will allow me to see every piece of specific engine, virtually dissemble it and such.

Comment: Most of these are manufacturer specific and not shared with anyone other than approved service centres, so I'm not sure whether you will get many useful answers to this one.

Comment: thought so... anyway, I hope some1 will answer some day :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that is true @RoryAlsop see the question below about the manufactures websites.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Hyundai, they make all of their repair procedures, schematics, etc. available at http://www.hmaservice.com (you must view this in IE btw) - I haven't seen this type of data available for free from any other manufacturers though.

This site has really nice auto repair videos for car repair for your exact model: http://www.carcarekiosk.com - it's for basic stuff like headlight bulbs, cabin air filters, etc., but the videos are very helpful and free.

Check the website of your local library, often they have a subscription to pay sites that are free to access if you enter your library car number.

Answer (score 2):

Alldatadiy is similar to Mitchell on Demand; some find the interface easier to use.
[Alldata](https://www.alldatadiy.com/)

Some sites that are not necessarily DIY, not free but can be most helpful if one can qualify for membership.

I-atn.com:  lots of threads on theory and technical discussions. Lots of help requests on specific problems. Membership has some restrictions. Moderate monthly fee.

Identifix.com:  Excellent fix database and OEM service data. Expensive monthly cost. This is the "go to" place for most professional automotive diagnosticians.

Comment: Congrats on hitting 5K

Comment: I love Identifix. Such a useful site.

Comment: @Ben  IDFix is the best. I hesitated a bit to mention it because it cause it is not DIY.

Answer (score 0):

There are physical repair manuals you can buy from a company called [Haynes.](http://haynes.com.au/)

The manuals are based on tearing down and rebuilding whatever car is in question and can be useful references if you are unsure the car you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Most manufactures have a website where repair data can be viewed and printed, some are easy to use some are almost impossible but the the info is in there.

Some examples are:

BMW: oss.bmw.de

Peugeot: serivebox.peugeot.com

VW: erwin.volkswagen.de

Audi: erwin.audi.com

Once you have an account set up you can pay for access in what ever time amount you want, normally 1 hour, 24hours, 1 week, 1 month and 1 year.

It has been law for many years now for any manufacture in the EU to allow 3rd parties to access repair info.

Comment: Do you know what citroën's site is?

Comment: http://service.citroen.com